# What is main difference between cloud storage and usual server storage?

Tags: cloud, cloud-storage, cloud-computing

Is it true that:

We can store data as well as run softwares on cloud storage, but servers are used to store and retrieve data only.

Information is synchronized in cloud storage, for example, in Facebook every one has his own personalized account. But in usual server storage, same information is sent to all set of users.

Comment: "Cloud" and "server" are synonymous... A "cloud" is a "remove server", but a "server" needs not be in a "cloud"

Comment: Refer to this https://www.znetlive.com/blog/5-differences-between-cloud-and-dedicated-servers/ it provides a difference between both may it help you to clear your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**, and you've got some interesting but incorrect assumptions going on.

*The Cloud* consists of servers operating in particular ways depending on the needs of the service(s) they provide, storing data and running applications.

*Servers* also operate in particular ways depending on the needs of the service(s) they provide, storing data and running applications.

In other words: All Clouds are built of servers, but not every server is used to host a Cloud.